# How to use CDI-@SessionScoped without a http-session

Tags: scope, jax-rs, java-ee-6, cdi

Can CDI-@Sessionscoped be used when no http-session is available (for example when a RESTful-WS is used?). And if not, is there an alternative to @SessionScoped? I'm asking because I need to have an application-state but I'm also forced to use JAX-RS.

For some reason, I can inject @SessionScoped beans in the RESTful-Service but I know that this, at least by convention, is not allowed. Also using @SessionScoped requires the JSessionID-Cookie to be send in the headers of each client-request and since the service is consumed in a non-browser-environment, I can't be sure that cookies can be used...

Answer (score 3):

In case of REST enviroment `@SessionScoped` will work as excepted in case of browser client (if REST server supports sessions) but will create new bean on every call in case of non-browser client (if client ignores coockies).

Maybe `@ApplicationScoped` is good for your?

Comment: Thank you for your answere. ApplicationScoped does not work, because I want the behaviour of SessionScoped. But I want the behaviour independent from the HTTP-Session. Do you know how I can achive that?

Comment: What are you mean exactly? You want use some different kind of session rather then http?

Comment: exactly. I want a SessionScope that is independent from a HTTP-Session. I want my own definition of session.

Comment: In such case you may try to implement custom CDI scope (http://adventuresintechology.blogspot.com/2012/04/custom-cdi-scopes.html)

Comment: What @MichailNikolaev is saying here I completely agree with. One other thing to consider however is the `@ConversationScope` maybe? http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#d0e1847

Comment: yes, you may try - but currently conversation scope not supported for REST out of the box

Comment: conversation scope also has the problem that it is dependent on HTTP-requests... I'll have a look at custom scopes.

Answer (score 2):

You could always create your own context and scope.